# How to get sum of products of all combinations in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, product

I'm using Python and 
I'm given an array like `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
and I want to find sum of all possible combination multiplications like:

For combinations of 1: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`

For combinations of 2:`1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + 4*1`.

For combination of 3: `1*2*3 + 1*3*4 + 2*3*4`

For combinations of 4: `1*2*3*4`

And finally sum of all these sums is my answer. I'm using `numpy.prod()` and `numpy.sum()`. But it's still too slow. Is there some better algorithm to find the sum quickly?

Comment: What about the combinations 1*3, 2*4, and 1*2*4? Also, how shall we tell whether our ideas are faster if you do not show your "slow" code?

Comment: @hpaulj Not an example, real code, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `numpy` and `itertools`:

```
from numpy import linspace, prod
from itertools import combinations

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])

[sum([prod(x) for x in combinations(arr,int(i))]) for i in linspace(1,len(arr), len(arr))]
[10, 35, 50, 24]
```