# Sum of Product of All Possible Combinations in an Array

Tags: algorithm, combinations

There is an array of **N** elements. I have to choose **K** elements and multiply them, say the value of multiplication is **M(k)**. Now add all possible **M(k)**. Say the sum is **S(k)**. Is it possible to determine all the values of **S(k)** (where 1 <= k <= N) in time-complexity of **O(N^2)**?

There is a solution in this forum in Python language but I don't know Python and beside this I want this problem to be solved generally.

Comment: A similar question was put on hold for being off topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908475/how-to-get-sum-of-products-of-all-combinations-in-an-array-in-python

Comment: A set of size N has 2^N - 1 possible subsets. A brute force solution would therefore have a complexity of O(2^N * N). I suggest you ask the folks at http://math.stackexchange.com if there is a faster algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you want is to expand the product of monomials

```
(1 + A[0] x) (1 + A[1] x) ... (1 + A[N-1] x)
```

and read off the coefficients of `x, x^2, ..., x^N`. There's an easy `O(N^2)`-time solution that uses the school algorithm to multiply in each factor one by one.